# Using RSocket `PayloadDecoder.ZERO_COPY` correctly

Tags: spring-boot, rsocket

In the [RSocket documentation](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-java) it says that using PayloadDecoder.ZERO_COPY will reduce latency and increase performance but:

> You must free the Payload when you are done with them or you will get a memory leak.

I'm using Spring and I can see lots of examples where ZERO_COPY is used - ([e.g. here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-rsocket)) - but no examples of special precautions to `free the payload`.

Can someone say what, if anything, needs to be done in this regard when using this feature.